# Maximum likelihood estimate of Gaussian parameters (1st-order Markov Chain)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, parameter-estimation

Let us assume the availability of a time series $x_1, \ldots, x_N$ (where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$).

If we assume each variable to be independent of all previous observations except the most recent, we obtain a first-order Markov chain. Under this model, the joint distribution $p(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ reads:

$$
p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = p(x_1) \prod_{n=2}^N p(x_n\,|\,x_{n-1}).
$$

Moreover, assume that the observations are generated from a Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

I would like to find the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. To this end, let us compute the log-likelihood function as follows:

$$
\ln p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \ln\left\{\mathcal{N}(x_1\,|\, \mu, \sigma^2)\right\} + \sum_{n=2}^N \ln\left\{p(x_n\,|\,x_{n-1})\right\}
$$

In order to complete the computation, I need to find the distribution of $(x_n\,|\,x_{n-1})$. Intuitively, I would assume $(x_n\,|\,x_{n-1})$ to distribute normally with mean $\bar{\mu}$ and variance $\bar{\sigma}^2$, both depending on the value of the observation $x_{n-1}$.

How can I explicitly express the distribution of $(x_n\,|\,x_{n-1})$? Should I decide a joint distribution for $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ (i.e., expressing $x_n$ as a function of $x_{n-1}$)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty with this question.  On one hand, you seem to be implying $p(x_n | x_{n-1}, \mu, \sigma)$ is a normal with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$ (the same distribution independent of $n$).  Then later you ask how to express $x_n$'s distribution in terms of $x_{n-1}$.  In the case of say $BM$ with a drift, you could have the mean of $x_n = x_{n-1} + \mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  But that is a different mean for each distribution of $x_n$.  So to be clear for my understand, $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are abstract parameters, not necessarily the actual mean and variance of each step?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the question accordingly. Hopefully, it should be clearer now.

Comment: No. Please reread the text you were given. Is each $x_n$ normal $(\mu,\sigma^2)$?